# Is it possible to generate an image (blob or data-url) in a web worker from a canvas context's getImageData?

Tags: javascript, canvas, web-worker, getimagedata, todataurl

**Background Setup**

I have a web application that deals with creating images from a set of other images. The way I've chosen to do that is by reading in a set of images and placing them on an HTML canvas. Then, I export each canvas as a jpeg to a third-party API using `toDataURL` and converting it into a Blob. The issue I am facing is that I have many of these canvases all exporting data as a jpg and it is consuming a lot of resources. The application slows and becomes unresponsive as each canvas attempts to call `toDataURL`.

**Question**

I've found that calling a canvas's `toDataUrl()` or `toBlob()` can be very slow especially for large canvas sizes. I'd like to utilize the multi-threaded nature of web workers.

First, I tried passing in the canvas object but an error was thrown. It turns out objects are a problem and that it seems they either get converted into strings or fail when they can't be cloned. Either way, I found that passing a context's image data does work. The data is passed in the form of raw RGB values as a `Uint8ClampedArray` from the canvas context's method `getImageData()`.

**Main.js**

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var worker = new Worker('myWorker.js');
worker.postMessage({
  image: context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
});
```

**myWorker.js**

```
this.onmessage = function(e) {
  // GOAL: turn e.data.image into an image blob or dataUrl and return it.
  // e.g. this.postMessage(new Blob([e.data.image.data], {type: 'image/jpg'});
}
```

I think it comes down to knowing how to convert a `Uint8ClampedArray` which holds the RGB information into the jpg/png data.

The reason why I think this might be useful is that I believe that `getImageData` just copies an existing data structure from the canvas context and therefore is not as costly as `toDataUrl`. I captured the cpu profile while calling something similar to the code block below:

```
var image = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```

and got:

[image: Performance results from getImageData and toDataURL]

So, given that, I'd like to offload the brunt of the process into a web worker. I don't even mind if it takes longer inside the web worker as long as its happening in another process.

Couple of extra thoughts about it:

- Adding an extra library to do the conversion is okay, but bonus points for offering how to add an external library as a dependency to web worker files. Right now I'm using browserify for the application. Perhaps create another browserified bundle for the web worker?
- I need a jpeg in the end (for a third party API) so converting it to a png is only so good as to be a step in the conversion to a jpeg.
- I've tried lowering the `encoderOptions`, the second option in `toDataURL`, as a way to speed up the process, but I haven't seen much of a change

Comment: That could be possible, but really hard and I'm unsure what benefit you'll have : You can create a Blob and send it back to the main page from a Web Worker. You can do the encoding to jpeg or png yourself (even if I would recommend searching for some libraries). Start with png, [the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Introduction.html) are clearer than jpeg. note : you'll need to also send the image's meta-data. But the heaviest operation is `ctx.getImageData()`. I'm not sure you'll win anything by passing the compression part to a Web Worker.

Comment: Maybe you should show us your code so we can tell if something can be improved from there. (e.g, do you use some asynchronous methods so the GUI doesn't block ?)

Comment: @Kaiido - I updated the question to reflect more of my understanding of the issue. It seems that getImageData isn't so onerous as expected. And as for my code, I'm using underscore's defer method to wrap the canvas.toDataURL so as to not lock the UI but as soon as the method begins (which it will eventually) it will block other js from executing. Also, it's worth noting that I'm doing this many times for many images on the page, so the cost is higher than the reported 400ms

Comment: I found a library that looks promising: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpeg-js
But when I plug it into my code it doesn't seem to be the right jpeg encoding that the browser typically uses. I created an issue in hopes to understand the difference better:
https://github.com/eugeneware/jpeg-js/issues/14

Answer (score 7):

**----UPDATE----**

I thought I would share my solution as an npm library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpeg-web-worker. It explains how to harness the provided web-worker to do the heavy lifting for you.

**---------------------**

I got a solution that works for me, speeding up the application and the responsiveness of the page while still generating the new images.

Here is the app code:

**App**

```
var canvas = $('#myCanvas')[0];
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var worker = new Worker('myWorker.js');
worker.postMessage({
  image: imageData
});
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
  var blob = new Blob( [e.data.data], {type: 'image/jpeg'} );
  // use blob
}
```

And here is the worker code:

**Worker**

```
this.onmessage = function(e) {
  var jpgInfo = encode(e.data.image, 50);
  this.postMessage(jpgInfo);
}

function encode() { ... } // ported from jpeg-js
```

Obviously, the bulk of this answer comes from the `encode` function. This function was modified from the npm module [jpeg-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpeg-js), and more specifically, the file [encoder.js](https://github.com/eugeneware/jpeg-js/blob/master/lib/encoder.js). I ported the encode function by copying the entire encoder.js file into my myWorker.js. It's not tiny but it's also very self contained which made it easy. The only issue I had left was modifying the code so that it worked outside of the node.js environment it was built for.

This turned out to be relatively easy:

1. Convert "const" variable declarations to "var"
2. Removing references to `Buffer`. This was a two step process. First, remove the atob definition (as it's not needed) at the top. Second, return a `new Unit8Array` at the end of the this.encode function. The current version actually has this commented out right above the buffer reference. Just use that one and remove everything underneath.
3. Removing reference to module.export. This is as easy as removing that line, as we only need this function within this file.

I don't have exact timing measurements but it went from ~10 seconds of lag time as the images were generated to under a second of lag time. I'm using "lag time" here to mean sluggish performance while using the page.

Comment: Note: look into OffscreenCanvas - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas. It may solve this usecase